# Creating a text deboss effect at small scale

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, illustrator-effects, drop-shadow

I'm trying to create a debossed effect in a small scale. It's a coin-like layout, but not using metallic gradients:

[image]

I've been working across Photoshop for image isolation/clean up, but ultimately want to create a vector in Illustrator. The design will be printed at 1" and I'm struggling to find a combination of text, shadow and deboss effects that will be visible at such a small size.

I've tried drop shadow, inner glow, and bevel and emboss.  Is this achievable, and if so how, or should I just use text fill/stroke that provide sufficient contrast instead?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can get for "Lucky Penny" with high contrast and high resolution printing

[image]

The effect is 3D-extruded hole in Illustrator, yellowish bottom is added.

Watch this far enough to see it relatively as big as a real button, then you see it right.

I recommend you to forget the idea, only real mechanical debossing  would look right in a physical button. Put your effort to have clean readable texts with good colors.

But if you still want to test the idea, see this older case for technical hints:

[Adobe Illustrator: Deboss or Engrave Effect](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119841/adobe-illustrator-deboss-or-engrave-effect)